# How can I limit wine's permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, wine

I don't want wine to:

- have access to the network (extra: separately defined access control per program that uses wine to start)
- have access to the main users files (run wine as different user??)

How can I do this? Are there any solutions?

(Using Ubuntu 11.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `winetricks` you can sandbox the wine prefix to remove all links to $HOME. I believe the command is `winetricks sandbox` but winetricks has changed so much lately I'm not positive.